# Makefile multiple target patterns

Tags: makefile

When trying to run my makefile (https://pastebin.com/CYqsYtj9), I run into an error:

```
C:/STM32_Projects/blink_project/test/cpputest/build/MakefileWorker.mk:485: *** multiple target patterns.  Stop.
```

I'm going to link the MakefileWorker.mk as well (https://pastebin.com/5JSy3HsB), even tho I'm pretty sure it's written properly since it's from https://github.com/cpputest/

So, question: why am I getting this error?

EDIT:
When I'm trying to make the makefile from Cygwin CLI, the error I get is the following:

```
C://STM32_Projects/blink_project//test/cpputest/build/MakefileWorker.mk:485: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
```

EDIT 2(Minimal, verifiable example):

```
    // test/main.cpp
#include "CppUTest/CommandLineTestRunner.h"

int main (int ac, char ** av){
    return CommandLineTestRunner::RunAllTests(ac,av);
}
```

so this is a simple main.cpp that my makefile should compile, other than that, you need a full repo from https://github.com/cpputest/cpputest compiled as shown in README in that repo.

Comment: Post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin If I understood correctly, I think I posted what you wanted.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin I edited my post with my main.cpp, other than that you have my makefile and cpputest library, that's everything I used, besides cygwin.

Comment: What does `$(TEST_DEPS)` expand to on line 485 of the makefile in question?

Comment: @G.M. $(TEST_DEPS) is used on 484, 485, 487 in the makefile, but I don't know what it expands to, it's definition is on line 484, but I didn't write that makefile.

Comment: Add `$(info TEST_DEPS=[$(TEST_DEPS)])` immediately after line 485 and check the output.  I realise `TEST_DEPS` appears on multiple lines but line 485 is the first point at which it is used to specify the dependencies in a rule.

Comment: @G.M. the output is absolutely the same, I get the multiple target patterns.

Comment: Sorry, I should have clearer.  When I said 'output' I was referring to the output from the `$(info TEST_DEPS=[$(TEST_DEPS)])` statement I suggested.  It should give you an idea of the value of `TEST_DEPS` at that point in the makefile.

Comment: @G.M. Trust me, it's not about you making it unclear, it's about me not knowing nearly enough about makefiles to know how to do that.

Comment: I'm going to assume, although you didn't say so, that you're running on Windows.  This error often happens because windows paths contain `:` which is a special character to makefiles.  As mentioned above you need to find out what the variable `TEST_DEPS` contains; until we know that there's nothing else we can do to help.  The `$(info ...)` line above should be put in the makefile right before the problem line, then run `make` as you normally do, and it should print out to the screen the contents of the variable right before the error message.

Comment: @MadScientist Yeah, I'm running Windows. The thing is, I put the `$(info...)` line right before the error line and this is what I get:
`$ make
TEST_DEPS=[objs/C:/STM32_Projects/blink_project/test/main.o   lib/libname_this_in_the_makefile.a   C:/STM32_Projects/blink_project/test/cpputest/lib/libCppUTest.a ]
C:/STM32_Projects/blink_project/test/cpputest/build/MakefileWorker.mk:486: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
`
this is the Cygwin CLI make

Comment: OK, well, the problem is right at the beginning: `objs/C:/STM...` is clearly wrong.  Maybe you tried to do something like `objs/$(TEST_DEPS)` somewhere?  You can't do that; make won't automatically propogate a prefix to every word in a variable.

Comment: Or, more likely, `TEST_OBJS`?

Comment: Note, if you're using cygwin make you almost certainly have to use cygwin paths: that is, convert `C:/foo` to `/c/foo` (I think, I don't actually use cygwin, or Windows for that matter)

Comment: @MadScientist So, the thing is, the only thing that I wrote is the first makefile, the one with like 9 lines. The other makefile with 500+ lines is cpputest makefile that works very well and is a library widely used. So if there was a mistake, it must have been on my part in the first makefile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, as mentioned I'm no expert when it comes to Windows and I know even less about cygwin.

But, my suspicion is that the environment you're trying to use is not well-supported or well-tested on Windows.  Here's what I see:

You set:

```
PROJECT_DIR=C:/STM32_Projects/blink_project
TEST_DIR=$(PROJECT_DIR)/test

TEST_SRC_DIRS=$(TEST_DIR)
```

which means `TEST_SRC_DIRS` is set to `C:/STM32_Projects/blink_project/test`.

Next in MakefileWorker.mk you get an error because `TEST_DEPS` is set to `objs/C:/STM32_Projects/blink_project/test/main.o ...` which, I hope we can all easily see, is a totally bogus path.

So how did we get this path?  Let's look backwards and see:

At line 484 we see how `TEST_DEPS` is set:

```
TEST_DEPS = $(TEST_OBJS) $(MOCKS_OBJS) ...
```

So, it's likely the bogus path is in `TEST_OBJS`.  That is set at line 380:

```
TEST_OBJS = $(call src_to_o,$(TEST_SRC))
```

First, what's `TEST_SRC`?  It's set on line 379 as the result of the user-defined macro `get_src_from_dir_list` with `TEST_SRC_DIRS` (which you set above).  That macro will locate all the source files, so files that match `*.cpp`, `*.cc`, and `*.c` in each directory in `TEST_SRC_DIRS`.  So based on the `info` output we can infer that this returns:

```
C:/STM32_Projects/blink_project/test/main.cpp
```

which is to be expected.  Then we pass that to `src_to_o` which is a user-defined macro on line 363, which uses another user-defined macro `src_to` defined on line 362:

```
src_to = $(addprefix $(CPPUTEST_OBJS_DIR)/,$(call __src_to,$1,$2))
```

Oho!!  Well, `CPPUTEST_OBJS_DIR` is set to `obj` at line 226, so this is very likely the start of our problem.

In a POSIX filesystem where there is no such abomination as a "drive letter", paths are fully constructable: if you have a fully-qualified path you can create another path by adding a new path as a prefix.  That can't work on Windows, where the drive letter must always come first.

But let's keep going.  So we see where the `obj/` prefix comes from, now where does the rest of the path come from?  That's the expansion of a user-defined macro `__src_to` defined at line 361 that starts with our source path above.  What does this do?  It wants to replace the `.cpp` extension with `.o`.  But note this bit here:

```
$(if $(CPPUTEST_USE_VPATH),$(notdir $2),$2)
```

If `CPPUTEST_USE_VPATH` is true then we return `notdir` of the path; this would strip out all the drive and directory info and return just `main.cpp` which would turn into `main.o` and then the result would be `obj/main.o`, which would work fine.

But if `CPPUTEST_USE_VPATH` is false (which it is by default), we don't strip off the path and `obj` is added to the full path with the drivespec and you get a syntax error.

So.  Basically, the cpputest makefiles have issues on Windows.  It looks like you have one of these choices:

Either set the `CPPUTEST_USE_VPATH` option to `Y` to enable it (and read about what that option means and how to use it in the cpputest docs),

Or, remove the drive specs from your paths in your makefile and just use:

```
PROJECT_DIR = /STM32_Projects/blink_project
```

which means you need to be careful that your current drive is `C:` before you invoke this else it won't be able to find things.

HTH!

Comment: The thing is, there are still errors in the makefile which still won't compile, but your answer gave me some direction in which to look for an answer, so I marked you as accepted.